# Curl not working with leading slash in data,

Tags: curl, git-bash, consul

My workstation is Windows, so I use Git Bash as a shell. This command:

```
curl -X PUT --data /app/envuser/logs http://consulidc01-dev1:8500/v1/kv/voice/common/logging.path
```

Actually transmits a value of `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/app/envuser/logs` instead of `/app/envuser/logs`. I've tried using `--data-raw` and `--data-binary` without success. I'm not sure if this is a `curl` issue or a GIT Bash issue. I want to get this working because I have a bash script that uploads all the Console properties. This is the only one not working. How can I prevent the undesired pre-pending of the Windows path?

Comment: curl certainly doesn't do that conversion. Does it help if you put quotes around the string?

Comment: No quotes do not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It was a GIT Bash issue. Before the curl command:

export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

Comment: Accept your own question then